# How to save output of repeat loop in parquet file?

Tags: scala, loops

I have a word "hi" written in loop.

```
implicit class Rep(n: Int) {
    def times[A](f: => A) { 1 to n foreach(_ => f) } 
}

// use it with
130.times { println("hi") }
```

How to save output?

Comment: There is some things unclear about your question. The above code *prints* "hi" 130 times. What output do you want to save? Where do you want to save it? To a variable, to a file? In both cases, you cannot save the output of `println` because you write the data to stdout.

Comment: I want to save "hi" 130 times in file .can I do that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some bugs in your code, here is a correct one:

```
implicit class Rep(n: Int) {
    def times[A](f: => A): Seq[A] = { 1 to n map(_ => f) } 
}

// use it with
val myHis = 130.times { "hi" } // returns Vector(hi, hi, hi, hi, hi, ...)
```

1. add `=` otherwise the functions return type is `Unit`- always add the return type explicit in such cases (`: Seq[A]`) and the compiler would have helped you.
2. use `map` instead of `foreach` as `foreach` returns again `Unit`
3. `println("hi")` returns again `Unit`. The last statement is returned, so it must be the value you want.

To write a file of this:

```
new java.io.PrintWriter("filename") { write(myHis.mkString(", ")); close }
```

Be aware this simple example does not handle exception properly - but I think `myHis.mkString(", ")` is what you are looking for.

Comment: can I save vector of "hi" in file ?

Comment: thanks,but I have something error java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/Desktop (No such file or directory).

Comment: check https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-write-text-files-in-scala-printwriter-filewriter

Comment: can I save number like  2.4848911616270923  which repeated  13849 times instead of "hi"?

Comment: can I save output in parquet file instead of txt because data is 13849 row.

Comment: sorry, I am not familiar with parquet. as you have a simple sequence it should not be a problem